# Predefined Term Mapping

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I have not yet used Elasticsearch so please excuse the bad description. I would like to know if it is possible to configure Elasticsearch to do the following - I had some issues in MongoDB with this as the full text search functionalities seem to be a little limiting.

> Here's my problem - when I do a search for the term `Korea` I do not
>   want it to match `North Korea` or `N. Korea` in the document.

The assumption is that a search for `Korea` is about `South Korea`. This is obviously different from a synonym as it is kind of the opposite. A phrase search for `South Korea` is out of the question here as it isn't applicable in my problem. Is this possible?

I will accept answers for either MongoDB or Elasticsearch.

Comment: "Here's my problem - when I do a search for the term Korea I do not want it to match North Korea or N. Korea in the document." but what you expect it to return?

Comment: I want the term not to match "North Korea" or "N. Korea" and therefore the results *should* return more about South Korea.

Comment: The issue here with my personal project is that, when people generally talk about Korea, they mean Samsung, LG, K-Pop etc. My app is returning a whole lot of stuff about nukes :S

Comment: You can make "south korea" weigh more for "korea" in ES

Comment: @Sammaye how do you do that?

Comment: Hmm, I was sure ES had this capacity but I can't find it now :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you use a query like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "some_field": "korea"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "-some_field:(\"north korea\")"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "-some_field:(\"n. korea\")"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What it does is like this:

- if that field content matches "korea" then it's receiving a score
- if that field isn't matching "north korea" again it's getting some score boost
- again, if it doesn't match "n. korea" is getting some additional score.

Basically, the score increases if it matches "korea", if it doesn't match "north korea" and if it doesn't match "n. korea".

For example, for documents like this

```
POST /my_index/test/1
{
  "text": "North Korea"
}
POST /my_index/test/2
{
  "text": "Korea"
}
POST /my_index/test/3
{
  "text": "N. Korea"
}
POST /my_index/test/4
{
  "text": "South Korea"
}
```

The query above will return this:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "korea",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.4471208,
        "_source": {
           "text": "Korea"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "korea",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.4227209,
        "_source": {
           "text": "South Korea"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "korea",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.48779577,
        "_source": {
           "text": "North Korea"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "korea",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.48779577,
        "_source": {
           "text": "N. Korea"
        }
     }
  ]
```

The highest scores are for documents that are not about north korea.

Comment: This is pretty cool - do you think a similar thing would be possible in MongoDB?

Comment: I have no idea about MongoDB.

Comment: @AndreiStefan just curios, can the same query be written using must_not (retaining the should) bool query instead of the query string?

Comment: @jrao77 yes, you can do that. And use `"type" : "phrase"` for a `match` query.